# Another geometry problem (length of side of a quadrilateral)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polygons

So this is the same question as my previous question, [A geometry problem (length of side of a quadrilateral)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539606/a-geometry-problem-length-of-side-of-a-quadrilateral/), but here we need to find AD [image]

I need to find AD in terms of AB, BC and $\theta$ only. I tried the same approach as https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1062486/insipidintegrator but did not reach anywhere. It would be help if someone gives some pointers

Comment: @insipidintegrator Please Help

Comment: Join BD. Applying Pythagorean, $AD^2=BD^2-AB^2$. Now in right triangle $BCD$, we have $BD=\frac{BC}{Cos\theta}$. Substituting in the above, we get $AD^2=(\frac{BC}{Cos\theta})^2-AB^2$. Please verify the calculations again.

Comment: What EXACTLY have you done? Please edit to say how you approached the problem. Just saying “same approach “ isn’t enough.

Answer (score -1):

Following what @ersh said, the exact solutions looks as,

[image]

(1) AD = AF + FD = BE + FD

(2) BE = $\frac{BC}{\cos{\theta}}$

(3) $\angle{ADC} = 90 - \theta \because$ Quadrilateral ABCD has two angles 90.

(4) FD = $\frac{EF}{\tan{(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta})}$ = $\frac{AB}{\tan{(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta})}$

Therefore,

AD =$\frac{BC}{\cos{\theta}}$ + $\frac{AB}{\tan{(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta})}$

Comment: Corrected @jaap-scherphuis